# readFileSync() dentro de una Promesa

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Tengo una consulta teórica, la cual involucra tanto lecturas de archivos como también operaciones asíncronas. cuando ejecuto la función `readFileSync()` dentro de una fución asíncrona (o sea una promesa), **¿Esta solo bloquea la ejecución de esa promesa o también bloquea la ejecución de todo el programa mientras lee?**

Para brindarles algo más de contexto, imaginemos que tenemos un pequeño api rest, en donde uno de sus endpoints es más o menos así:

```
// Instancia de express
app.post('/form/save', async (req, res) => {
  // Guardar formulario en la base de datos
  const form = parseBody(req);
  await form.save(); 

  // Revisar síntomas
  if (form.symptoms.length > 0) {
    // Buscar emails del personal del área
    const position = form.employee.position;
    const manager = await Manager.find({ position });

    // Crear email con los datos del formulario
    const file = new HtmlFile('../res/email-template.html');
    const html: string = file.parse({
      name: form.employee.name,
      symptoms: form.sympthoms.map(x => x.descript),
    });

    // Preparar emails
    const mail = new Mail(html, manager.map(x => {
      return {
        name: x.name,
        email: x.email
      };
    });

    // Send emails
    await mail.send();
  }

  res.helper.json({ alert: form.sympthoms.length });
});
```

HtmlFile es una clase que creé, la cual extiende a otra clase (`HtmlParser`), y se estructura de la siguiente forma:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { HtmlParser } from './html-parser';

export class HtmlFile extends HtmlParser {
  constructor(path: string) {
    super('');

    const reso = resolve(path);
    const html = readFileSync(reso, 'utf8');
    super.raw = html;
  }
}
```

Como se puede ver, esta clase utiliza `readFileSync()` en el constructor, lo cual, al llamar al constructor desde mi endpoint, debería de bloquear la ejecución de esa tarea. Mi pregunta concreta es **¿Esa llamada solo bloquea la ejecución de esta promesa (la cual es asíncrona) o también bloquea a todo el programa?**

### Solución

Considerando la información expuesta por @trauma:

> Cualquier cosa con el postfijo Sync te bloqueará todo el thread.

...y también lo expuesto [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604866/difference-between-readfile-and-readfilesync):

> [...] nunca se debe llamar a `readFileSync()` en un webservice o proyecto de Express, ya que bloqueará el thread *(lo cual incluiría al resto de endpoints)* hasta que termine la operación de I/O.

Dicho sea el caso, la clase `HtmlFile` ha sido modificada para tener en un método aparte la lectura del archivo de forma **asíncrona** *(envuelto en una promesa)*:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { readFile } from 'fs';
import { HtmlParser } from './html-parser';

export class HtmlFile extends HtmlParser {
    private _path : string;
    public get path() : string {
        return this._path;
    }

    constructor(path: string) {
        super(null);
        this._path = resolve(path);
    }

    load(): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            readFile(this._path, (fail, byte) => {
                if (fail) {
                    reject(fail);
                } else {
                    try {
                        this._raw = byte.toString('utf8');
                        resolve();
                    } catch (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

...y en cuanto al endpoint (solo la parte relacionada):

```
    // Buscar emails del personal del área
    const position = form.employee.position;
    const manager = await Manager.find({ position });

    // Cargar template del html
    const file = new HtmlFile('../res/email-template.html');
    await file.load();    // Aquí lectura asíncrona del archivo

    // parsear html con los datos del formulario
    const html: string = file.parse({
      name: form.employee.name,
      symptoms: form.sympthoms.map(x => x.descript),
    });

    // Preparar emails
    const mail = new Mail(html, manager.map(x => {
      return {
        name: x.name,
        email: x.email
      };
    });

    // Send emails
    await mail.send();
  }
```

Comment: Bloquea **todo el programa**.

Comment: ya veo, o sea que en este caso, ¿No me quedaría de otra que usar `readFile()` supongo, envolverlo en una __promesa__ y llamarla en una función aparte del constructor para que __únicamente me bloquee la ejecución del endpoint asíncrono__ y no todo el programa?

Comment: Cualquier cosa con el postfijo *Sync* te bloqueará **todo el thread**. Como te organices ... pues ya a tu gusto :-) Múltiples [threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads), promesas, funciones con callbacks, ...

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. Lo tendré en cuenta para mis futuros desarrollos. Actualizaré mi pregunta con la solución que implementé en base a tus indicaciones.